# Available Times From The Date Selected

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am creating a booking system, I have got it all working so that a user can select a date and a time and book, there are no restrictions so 100 people could book the same date and time.

My lecturer suggested to me that to make it so that just one person can book one time on one day the user will select a date and then the page will re-load with the times selector only showing the times which are available on this date.

I have done some tutorial work similar to this, however a little more basic showing the available slots using an except operation for example allavailableslots except bookedslots, but there was no restriction on dates, so it would just show all the times which havent been booked yet full stop.

I think I will use an if statement but I am not too sure, dont really know where to start...

If it helps my tables and fields are as follows

**App**

- Bookingid
- Petid
- Vetid
- Date
- StartTime

**Slot**

- StartTime

Any help is much appreciated and if you need any further information please ask away, otherwise any links to further help I could get or ideas about how I would go about this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You  can acheive by left outer join and select all the start time from s for those there is no Bookingid

```
SELECT a.Bookingid,s.StartTime
FROM Slot s
LEFT OUTER JOIN App a ON s.StartTime = a.StartTime 
WHERE a.Bookingid= null And a.Date=DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: When it comes to declaring 'a' and 's' do you know what I would declare them as?

Comment: a and s are aliasing for table name Slot s now you can refer table Slot with s in your query.